# Automatic random primary key within a specific range in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, default-value, recursive-query

I would like to automatically insert a primary key every time I add a new record to an SQLite3 table, much like a PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT except that the value should be randomly chosen from some range (say 0000 through 9999) rather than being assigned sequentially.

For demonstration purposes, let's restrict the range to 1 through 6 instead and try to populate the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dice (rolled INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
```

Now every time I insert a new record into that table, I want a new random primary key to be created.

The following works and does exactly what I want

```
INSERT INTO dice VALUES(
    (
        WITH RECURSIVE roll(x) AS (
                VALUES(ABS(RANDOM()) % 6 + 1)
            UNION ALL
                SELECT x % 6 + 1 FROM roll
        )
        SELECT x FROM roll WHERE (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dice where rolled = x
        ) = 0 LIMIT 1
    )
);
```

except that I have to invoke it manually/explicitly.

Is there any way to embed the above (or an equivalent) calculation for the random primary key into a DEFAULT clause for the "rolled" column or into some sort of trigger, so that a new key will be calculated automatically every time I insert a record?

Comment: if you use some programming language to access, better use that programming language to make that primary key

Comment: @keronconk - Thanks four your suggestion, but I would prefer to decouple the database from any applications accessing it. That way, the core logic of the record handling (including default values) remains in one central place, within the database itself.